# What might the pros and cons for Embedded Arrays VS flat documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am a newbie to mongodb , I have a scenario where there will be (example)

1. Users collection
2. Each Users can have maximum of 10 habits .

**There is two options infront of me**

1. Create a collection like UserHabits and add the habits as **embedded
   array** .
2. Add each habits as each **documents** .

What might be the **cons and pros** for these two approaches . Thanks .

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Answer (score 0):

With a one:few relationship in MongoDB, it is almost always more beneficial to embed the doc for performance reasons. The only cons to working with embedded docs are:

1. If for some reason you open the habits option up to say where a person could select 1,000,000 habits, the document might exceed the maximum size of 16MB.
2. You open yourself up to inconsistency if a user can enter different values into habits (ex. One user's habit it 'flying a kite' and one user's habit is 'kite flying'). However, if you have normalized data, this won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! 16MB :)

Comment: RE point 2: this inconsistency depends on how user inputs the habits. If it's a free-form text input (which allows users to create new habits), such inconsistency is bound to happen, regardless of how it's stored. On the other hand, if it's a fixed dropdown (with a server-side inclusion validation), then it won't happen (again, regardless of storage shape)